# How to add logo in upper left and right corner of baposter

Tags: graphics, positioning, baposter, wide-image

I am creating a poster using baposter. I have to add 04 logos to the poster, out of which one of the logos in upper left and another in upper right corner of the poster. Remaining 02 can be inline with Title. However all the  coming inline with title. The file baposter.cls is available here [baposter.cls](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/). The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here fontscale=0.285
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are storedhttps://www.overleaf.com/project/5f12e7a80c36e30001056c20
\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers
\definecolor{green1}{cmyk}{0.2,0.8,0.0,0.2}
\definecolor{darkblue}{cmyk}{0.8,0.2,0.0,0.8}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.0,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.0,0.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.3\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\begin{tabular}{ll}
              \includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{logo.png} &
              \includegraphics[height=3em, width = 3em]{logo.png} 
              \end{tabular}
              }
% {\includegraphics[height=1.5 em, width = 2.5 em]{logo.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsf{\textcolor{darkblue}{A very long Title}}\vspace{0.2em}} % Poster title
{\textsf{}}\vspace{0.1em}\\{}
% Author names and institution
{\begin{tabular}{cc}
              \includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{logo.png} \\
              \includegraphics[height=3.75em, width = 3.75em]{logo.png} 
              \end{tabular}
              }
 % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=1,column=0,row=0, span = 2}{}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have these error `! LaTeX Error: File "baposter.cls" not found.` Where do you find this class?

Comment: Hi it is available at (http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)

Comment: Place this link in your question so that users who want to help you don't have to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You can set a logo on the left of the title by adding `eyecatcher=true` and then using `\includegraphics...` to add the logo. The logo on the right is also added using `\includegraphics...`. To get logos in the upper left and right of the page, you can apply them on the background using the `\background` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here fontscale=0.285
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are storedhttps://www.overleaf.com/project/5f12e7a80c36e30001056c20
\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers
\definecolor{green1}{cmyk}{0.2,0.8,0.0,0.2}
\definecolor{darkblue}{cmyk}{0.8,0.2,0.0,0.8}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.0,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.0,0.25}

\begin{document}
\background{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{example-image-a}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightgreen, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.3\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt, % Width of the border lines around content boxes
background=user %<-- added
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{example-image-a}} %<-- eyecatcher
% {\includegraphics[height=1.5 em, width = 2.5 em]{logo.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{darkblue}{A very long Title}} % Poster title
%{\textsf{}}\vspace{0.1em}\\{}
% Author names and institution
{Authors}
{\includegraphics[height=2em, width = 2em]{example-image-a}}
 % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{posterbox}[name=1,column=0,row=0, span = 2]{Introduction}
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ross but still my upper logos are not at corners. I need one logo at the upper left and right corner each and another two logos inline with the title..

Comment: I corrected this. I can add more explanation if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks, but logos in background are not getting displayed.

Comment: Code is working in new file but not in existing file, I will figure out and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Ross! It worked